# Creating pandas profile fails due to None category_alias_name

Tags: pandas, python-3.11

Creating pandas profile fails due to None category_alias_name

```py
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
profile = ProfileReport(df.fillna('unknown'), title="Opportunity Profiling Report", minimal=True)
```

Then generating the pandas profile:

```py
profile.to_notebook_iframe()
```

It fails due category_alias_name being None

I tried filling nan with 'unknown' and setting a minimal report without success.

Full stacktrace:

```
Summarize dataset: 100%|█████████████| 25/25 [00:01<00:00, 14.54it/s, Completed]
Generate report structure:   0%|                          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 1
----> 1 profile.to_notebook_iframe()

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:498, in ProfileReport.to_notebook_iframe(self)
    496 with warnings.catch_warnings():
    497     warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
--> 498     display(get_notebook_iframe(self.config, self))

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/widget/notebook.py:75, in get_notebook_iframe(config, profile)
     73     output = get_notebook_iframe_src(config, profile)
     74 elif attribute == IframeAttribute.srcdoc:
---> 75     output = get_notebook_iframe_srcdoc(config, profile)
     76 else:
     77     raise ValueError(
     78         f'Iframe Attribute can be "src" or "srcdoc" (current: {attribute}).'
     79     )

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/presentation/flavours/widget/notebook.py:29, in get_notebook_iframe_srcdoc(config, profile)
     27 width = config.notebook.iframe.width
     28 height = config.notebook.iframe.height
---> 29 src = html.escape(profile.to_html())
     31 iframe = f'<iframe width="{width}" height="{height}" srcdoc="{src}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
     33 return HTML(iframe)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:468, in ProfileReport.to_html(self)
    460 def to_html(self) -> str:
    461     """Generate and return complete template as lengthy string
    462         for using with frameworks.
    463 
   (...)
    466 
    467     """
--> 468     return self.html

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:275, in ProfileReport.html(self)
    272 @property
    273 def html(self) -> str:
    274     if self._html is None:
--> 275         self._html = self._render_html()
    276     return self._html

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:383, in ProfileReport._render_html(self)
    380 def _render_html(self) -> str:
    381     from ydata_profiling.report.presentation.flavours import HTMLReport
--> 383     report = self.report
    385     with tqdm(
    386         total=1, desc="Render HTML", disable=not self.config.progress_bar
    387     ) as pbar:
    388         html = HTMLReport(copy.deepcopy(report)).render(
    389             nav=self.config.html.navbar_show,
    390             offline=self.config.html.use_local_assets,
   (...)
    398             version=self.description_set.package["ydata_profiling_version"],
    399         )

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/profile_report.py:269, in ProfileReport.report(self)
    266 @property
    267 def report(self) -> Root:
    268     if self._report is None:
--> 269         self._report = get_report_structure(self.config, self.description_set)
    270     return self._report

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/structure/report.py:386, in get_report_structure(config, summary)
    367 section_items: List[Renderable] = [
    368     Container(
    369         get_dataset_items(config, summary, alerts),
   (...)
    373     ),
    374 ]
    376 if len(summary.variables) > 0:
    377     section_items.append(
    378         Dropdown(
    379             name="Variables",
    380             anchor_id="variables-dropdown",
    381             id="variables-dropdown",
    382             is_row=True,
    383             classes=["dropdown-toggle"],
    384             items=list(summary.variables),
    385             item=Container(
--> 386                 render_variables_section(config, summary),
    387                 sequence_type="accordion",
    388                 name="Variables",
    389                 anchor_id="variables",
    390             ),
    391         )
    392     )
    394 scatter_items = get_interactions(config, summary.scatter)
    395 if len(scatter_items) > 0:

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/structure/report.py:161, in render_variables_section(config, dataframe_summary)
    159     variable_type = summary["type"]
    160 render_map_type = render_map.get(variable_type, render_map["Unsupported"])
--> 161 template_variables.update(render_map_type(config, template_variables))
    163 # Ignore these
    164 if reject_variables:

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/structure/variables/render_text.py:95, in render_text(config, summary)
     93 unitab = None
     94 if characters and "category_alias_counts" in summary:
---> 95     overview_table_char, unitab = render_categorical_unicode(config, summary, varid)
     96     overview_items.append(overview_table_char)
     98 unique_stats = render_categorical_frequency(config, summary, varid)

File ~/work/ml_experiments/theydo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ydata_profiling/report/structure/variables/render_categorical.py:139, in render_categorical_unicode(config, summary, varid)
    135 cats = []
    136 for category_alias_name, category_alias_counts in sorted(
    137     summary["category_alias_char_counts"].items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[1])
    138 ):
--> 139     category_alias_name = category_alias_name.replace("_", " ")
    140     cats.append(
    141         FrequencyTable(
    142             freq_table(
   (...)
    150         )
    151     )
    153 category_items = [
    154     category_overview,
    155     Container(
   (...)
    162     ),
    163 ]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Answer (score 0):

This does seems to be a bug  from the package. But I'm not sure what version are you using here. The latest release? https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/4.3.1/

Maybe I suggest to open an issue as this seems to be a bug: github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling